# How to paginate custom post type in wordpress of custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I want to implement pagination on custom post type of a custom taxonomy.
but it is not showing the pagination links only shows on default posts but not working. When I click on **next link** it redirect me to the **index** page.
Any help.(**New to Wordpress**)

**Code**

```
<?php $term = get_queried_object();
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($term->taxonomy);

            ?>
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4><?php echo 'محصولات : '.$term->name;?></h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array('post_type'=>'my_product', 'taxonomy'=>$taxonomy->name,
                        'posts_per_page'=> 1,
                        'term'=>$term->slug, 'paged'=>$paged);
                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('featured');
                            } ?>
                            <div class="caption caption-content">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p class="text-muted">
                                    <!-- <strong>نویسنده:</strong> <?php //the_author();?>  -->
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; تاریخ: <?php the_date(); ?></p>
                                <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="price-box">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>قیمت:
                                        <?php if (the_field('price') == '') {
                                            // echo "00.00";
                                        } else {
                                            the_field('price');
                                        } ?>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                }
                else {
                    echo '<h3>هیچ موردی درین بخش یافت نشد.</h3>';
                }
                ?>

                <!-- pagination here -->
                <p> <?php
                      if (function_exists("custom_pagination")):
                          custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
                      endif;
                    ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </p>

            </div>
```

Comment: This is my next page default post url:  ( http://localhost/project/category/news/page/2 )

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/

Comment: Not working, here my page name is taxonomy-product_category.php and it is not showing the pagination link.